# Pandas appending rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a list, like below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [4, 5, 6], 'month': [1, 2, 3]})

list = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to create a new column that contains each one of list items in that column, with the same rows, like this:

```
   x    month week
0  4      1     1
1  5      2     1
2  6      3     1
3  4      1     2
4  5      2     2
5  6      3     2
6  4      1     3
7  5      2     3
8  6      3     3
```

I tried looping, like, taking df and creating the new column and appending that result into a list, but i ended with a list that only contains the last df created.

```
l = []
k = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [4, 5, 6], 'month': [1, 2, 3]})
for i in range(0,len(k)):
    df['Semana'] = k[i]
    l.append(df)
```

Help :((

Comment: `pd.merge(df.assign(key=1), pd.DataFrame({'week':lst, 'key':1}),
         on='key').drop('key', axis=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this just via for loop and pd.concat function -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [4, 5, 6], 'month': [1, 2, 3]})

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(list1)):
    df['week'] = list1[i]
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df])

final_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**output -**

```
    x   month   week
0   4   1       1
1   5   2       1
2   6   3       1
3   4   1       2
4   5   2       2
5   6   3       2
6   4   1       3
7   5   2       3
8   6   3       3
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, I have just created new lists for each columns using for loops

```
import pandas as pd
x = []
month = []
week = []
k = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [4, 5, 6], 'month': [1, 2, 3]})

for i in range(0,len(k)):
    for j in df['x']:
        x.append(j)

for i in range(0,len(k)):
    for j in df['month']:
        month.append(j)

for j in k:
    for i in range(0,len(k)):
        week.append(j)
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'month':month, 'week':week })
print(df)
```

```
   x  month  week
0  4      1     1
1  5      2     1
2  6      3     1
3  4      1     2
4  5      2     2
5  6      3     2
6  4      1     3
7  5      2     3
8  6      3     3
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:-** Before moving ahead to Solution. This query has been resolved using Conversion on Data type of `list`.

So, I have taken Dataset Mentioned in your Query and Print it.

```
# Import all Libraries
import pandas as pd

# Declaration of DataFrame and List
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [4, 5, 6], 'month': [1, 2, 3]})
list = [1, 2, 3]

# Print Records of DataFrame
df
```

```
# Output of Above Code
    x   month
0   4   1
1   5   2
2   6   3
```

Now, According to our desired Output. We can see a repetition of `x` and `month` Columns. For achieving this output kindly follow the steps given below:-

```
# 'pd.concat()' Function for Repeatation of Data 'len(list) times' or '3 times{in our case}' 
df = pd.concat([df]*len(list), ignore_index = True)

# Print Updated DataFrame
df
```

```
# Output of Above Code

    x   month
0   4   1
1   5   2
2   6   3
3   4   1
4   5   2
5   6   3
6   4   1
7   5   2
8   6   3
```

After this step, we can move towards our last step. Which Appending `week` Data to `df` in the Repetitive format with respect to above-Generated Result. Kindly follow the steps given below:-

```
# Conversion of 'list' to 'Series' Type 
week = pd.Series(list)

# Repeatation of 'week' data 'len(list) times' or '3 times {in our case}'
week = week.repeat(len(list))

# 'reset_index()' for Reseting Index
week = week.reset_index(drop = True)

# Conversion of 'Series' to 'DataFrame' Type 
week = pd.DataFrame(x)

# Print 'Week DataFrame' Records
week
```

```
# Output of Above Code

    0
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   3
7   3
8   3
```

Now, at last, append the above generated `week` data into `df` for generating final Output

```
# Append 'Week DataFrame" with "Main DataFrame" 
df["week"] = week

# Print Final DataFrame
df
```

```
# Final Output of Above Code

    x   month   week
0   4   1       1
1   5   2       1
2   6   3       1
3   4   1       2
4   5   2       2
5   6   3       2
6   4   1       3
7   5   2       3
8   6   3       3
```

Hope this solution will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much.